# Confusion with the parameters of C's fwrite function

Tags: c, fwrite, fread

I am now learning the C language. I came across `fread` and `fwrite` functions in tutorialspoint.com. Basically, the declaration for both of these functions are kinda the same:

`size_t fread(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream)`

`size_t fwrite(const void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream)`

There are some examples for each of these functions in that website. As for the `fwrite` function:

`fwrite(str , 1 , sizeof(str) , fp );`

And I can totally understand this. But as for the `fread` function:

`fread(buffer, strlen(c)+1, 1, fp);`

Why the `1` argument come after the `strlen(c)+1` argument? Is this some kind of mistake or there is something I should know?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have a link to that specific example?

Comment: It doesn't really matter. You can think of reading or writing 1 char array of size N, or N separate characters of size 1 each.

Comment: @2501 The links are here http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fread.htm and http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fwrite.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading e.g. [this `fread` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fread), or [this `fread` POSIX specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fread.html) tell us that the `size` argument is the size of each *element* (e.g. `sizeof(some_type)`), while `nmemb` is the *number* of elements to read (e.g. `strlen(some_string)`). The same goes for `fwrite` of course.

In most cases though, switching places of the values passed doesn't matter, *if* everything works okay then `size * nmemb` bytes will be read (or written). The problems comes when there's error reading from or writing to the file, so it's best to try and remember which argument is which.

Answer (score 2):

> Why the 1 argument come before the sizeof(str) argument?

`1` is `sizeof( char )`

The `fwrite` should be better written as:

`fwrite(str , sizeof(char) , sizeof(str) , fp );`

Comment: There is totally no point in sizeof(char) because it is 1 by standard.

Comment: @coredump Yes, there is, it makes the code readable and signals intent.

Comment: @coredump - it's always better to write `sizeof(char)` instead of `1`. Have you heard of magic numbers? `1` can mean many things, it can mean `sizeof(char)`, it also can mean `true`. On the other hand, when you write `sizeof(char)` there is no such ambiguity.

Comment: The problem in the OP's code is with `fread` and not with `fwrite`

Comment: @artm - OP, wrongly accepted the code for `fread` as correct. and on that basis thought that `fwrite` was wrong. While it was the other way round.

Comment: @Rishi Yup. It looks like I was wrong. Gonna fix it right away! Thanks for pointing it.

Answer (score 1):

From [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fwrite/)

> **Size** - Size in bytes of each element to be written. size_t is an unsigned integral type.
>
> **Count** - Number of elements, each one with a size of size bytes.
> size_t is an unsigned integral type.

You can interchange the size and the count and it will not make any difference in the normal case. As mentioned by *2501*, it will make a difference if the no of elements cannot be read from the file.

The example given will work in the normal case, but should be corrected to give proper values for `size` and `count` for `fread`

```
fread(buffer, 1, strlen(c)+1, fp);
```

Comment: Not, true, changing the size of the element,(size parameter) will change the behavior if the function fails to read an element. The return value will be different.